# How to reboot or switch off Genymotion device?

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I'm following a guide of installing Google Play in a Genymotion VM. The guide says to run `adb reboot`. How do I do that?

A comment to the guide asked the same question and someone replied to that: `adb connect 192.168.56.101` followed by `adb -e reboot` . But entering the first command gives me error:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

Long pressing power button on the emulator, brings up option inside Android to turn off the device but when I try to turn off the device this way (through Android), the emulator hangs on "Shutting down..." and doesn't turn off the device.

Linux Mint 17 ; Genymotion 2.3.1 ; Android 4.4.4

Comment: why not just use reboot button in genymotion vm.

Comment: @turtle I can't see a reboot button but there's a power button, which is not working as desired as I've already explained. Anyway, the question is solved now.

Comment: @gom what exactly you did to solve this problem?

Comment: @Kriti i've already tick-marked an answer and also commented on it. it's been a long time but i think simply closing the window may also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `adb` installed as part of your Linux distribution, then your `PATH` probably points there. Chances are this `adb` is version 1.0.31 (or earlier).

Genymotion comes with its own `adb` in the `tools/` directory, which is version 1.0.32 if you are running the latest Genymotion, currently 2.3.1. Unless you changed it in the settings, Genymotion will start the bridge with that copy.

Since `adb` operates in a client-server arrangement, the client version should match the daemon version. In your case, they don't and that's why you're getting the `adb server is out of date.  killing...` message. If the daemon is killed or dies, the Genymotion launcher automatically and immediately restarts `adb` (using its own copy), and that's why your client can't start a new daemon bound to port 5037.

The solution is to make sure that the version of `adb` you are invoking on the command line matches the one that Genymotion is bringing up as a daemon when it starts the VMs. The easiest way to ensure this is just to use the `adb` binary in Genymotion's `tools/` directory.

Note that if you have changed Genymotion's default of using its own tools to use custom SDK tools, then you'll need to use an `adb` client that matches the version contained in the SDK you're pointing to. As far as I can tell, KitKat (4.4.4) and earlier SDKs contain `adb` version 1.0.31, while the Lollipop (5.0) SDKs have 1.0.32.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! As per your answer, I did `reboot` using the `adb` binary in Genymotion's `tools/` directory and it worked. I had installed `adb` in my Linux through `apt-get install android-tools-adb` and yes you're right that that `adb version` is 1.0.31 and `adb` in `tools/` is 1.0.32 .

Comment: I don't understand anything , kindly guide me step by step to solve this problem

Answer (score 9):

**Just go to your Genymotion Installation directory:**

For my PC: C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools

**Open command prompt and navigate to this directory:**

(cd C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools)

**C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools>**

and type command:

**adb reboot**

Answer (score 3):

I had trouble using adb, but found if you long-press on the power button it will bring up the power menu and do a full shutdown, rather than a snapshot and suspend.